# Let $f:\{1,2,3...,10\}\to \mathbb{Z}$ be a function such that $|f(i)-i|=p,\forall i\in\{1,2,3,...,10\}$.If maximum value of $f(x)$ is $15$ then find

Tags: algebra-precalculus, permutations, permutation-cycles

Let $f:\{1,2,3...,10\}\to \mathbb{Z}$ be a function such that $|f(i)-i|=p,\forall i\in\{1,2,3,...,10\}$. If maximum value of $f(x)$ is $15$ then find

(i) number of possible values of $p$

(ii)number of such functions

(iii)minimum value of $f(x)$

**My Attempt**

I took $f(i)-i=\pm p$. So $f(i)=i\pm p$ which should mean that $i\pm p\leq 15$ which means $p$ can only take the value $5$. I don't understand how to proceed further

Comment: Answer $p=5$ is not unique. Let $p=6$. Let $f(10)=4$, $f(9)=15$. Then ${\rm max} f(x)=15$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Yes. So how can we count such functions

Comment: I believe, you need to solve question (i) before (ii). $f(x)\leq 15$, $f(x)=x+p \lor f(x)=x-p$. Let count functions $f$ for $p=9$ for example. For $a>6$: $a+9 > 15$, then for $a>6$: $f(a)=a-9$, then for $6<a\leq 10$: $f(a)\leq 1$. For $a<6$: $a+9<15$, then for $a<6$: $f(a)<15$. Then maximum value 15 can be obtained only at $a=6$. Then $f(6)=15$. For each $a>6$ there is only one option for $f(a)=a-9$. For each $a<6$ there are two options for $f(a)=a\pm 9$. Then there are $2^5$ possible functions $f$ for $p=9$.

Comment: As for question (iii) there are many possible answers. Function $f(x)=x+5$ fits to the problem and has ${\rm min} f(x)=6$. Function $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=x-5$ for $x<10$ and $f(x)=15$ for $x=10$ also fits to the problem and has ${\rm min} f(x)=-4$. Maybe problem requires to find minimum **possible** value of $f(x)$.